# How to select and put preventDefault() to links with a particular class

Tags: jquery

How can I get all the links with a particular class and set them the preventDefault()?

I have this code throwing this error

```
$("document").ready(function(){
if($("a.particulaClass").length>0){
    var theGroup = $("a.particulaClass")
    for(var i=0;i<theGroup.length;i++){
        theGroup.eq(i).preventDefault();
    }
}})
```

**Uncaught TypeError: seleccion.eq(...).preventDefault is not a function**

I guess it´s because it´s not a jQuery object, but then, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`preventDefault()` must be used on an event, not an element.

Simply add an event listener on the click on your `a.particulaClass`

```js
$(document).on('click','a.particulaClass', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I don´t want to select them with a click, I have a setInterval checking if they exist or not... I don´t want any interaction to make this work and if I can´t use it out of an event, I guess I need another solution then :(

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Don't use a setInterval. This solution is way better, since it doesn't trigger every X milliseconds.

Comment: Yeah, but I repeat, I wanted to do it without any interaction at all, anyway, I´m gonna do it with a click, yes :)

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var intervalo = setInterval(function(){
if(jQuery("a.vc_gitem-link").length>0){
clearInterval(intervalo)
            jQuery("a.vc_gitem-link").click(function(e){
                console.log("clicked")
                e.preventDefault();
            })
        }
    }, 500);
})`



I´m getting the "clicked" but the <a> is still linking... I don´t get it.

Comment: @torpedete Delete that setInterval. The click handler only has to be defined once.

Comment: But those links are generated after a gallery is completely loaded, I need to check that they are created and $(document).load() is not being fired

Comment: The event handler is attached to the document, it doesn't matter if the elements are not added at the time the event handler is declared. It will still work.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.vc_gitem-link").click(function(e){
        console.log("clicked")
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})`


Still not working... I don´t know what I´m missing

Comment: @torpedete Use my code ..., yours won't work since it attaches the event handler to the elements directly.

Comment: Still not working @Zenoo...


`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click','a.vc_gitem-link', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})`

Comment: @torpedete It does. If you have an issue, it's somewhere else in your code. Post a snippet showing it not working. I can't help you blind.

Comment: I guess it´s because this is integrated into a Wordpress site and maybe something is failing, but I don´t get any single error and this is the only code I have in my custom.js file